# Check value inside Map

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a Map where I save values with the form `NAME-GROUP`.

Before doing some operations, I need to know if the Map contains a specific group, 
for example: I need to check for values containing `group1` like `Mark-group1`.

I'm trying to get it this way:

```
if (checkList.containsValue(group1)) {
    exists = true;
}
```

I can't provide the name when searching because there could be diferent names with the same group.

But it isn't finding the value, as seems that this function just looks for the entire value string and not only for part of it.

So, there would be any way of achieving this, or would I need to change the way I'm focusing my code.

**Update--**

This is the looking of my Map:

```
Map<Integer, String> checkList = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

I load some values from a database and I set them into the Map:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    int checkKey = 0;
    do {
        checkKey++;
        checkList.put(checkKey, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TravelOrder.RELATION)));
    }while(c.moveToNext());
}
```

The relation column, has values like: `mark-group1`, `jerry-group1`, `lewis-group2`, etc...
So, the Map will have a structure like `[1, mark-group1]`, etc...

What I need is to check if there is any value inside the map that contains the string `group1` for example, I don't care about the name, I just need to know if that group exists there.

Comment: I don't know all the possibilities of android, but in my opinion you'll need to iterate througth the keys and use something like `mymap.key(id).matches(regex)`

Comment: @Patrick Ferreira If I've understood you right, I can't use the ID as reference, the map's values are  variable, there aren't always in the same place so they don't have always the same ID. That's why I need to search using the group string

Comment: Actually it is a simple Java question nothing have to do with Android. What do you mean by *But it isn't finding the value, as seems that this function just looks for the entire value string and not only for part of it*? That function checks whether the map contains the group1 object by using the `equals` method.

Comment: @WonderCsabo I'm not sure about that, is a deduction to where I've arrived, because debuging I can see that f.e. the value Mark-group1 exists inside the map, but when doing the check posted above, it tells me that the value group1 doesn't exists inside the Map.

Comment: That is not possible. If the `Map` has a key1-value1 mapping, then `containsValue(value1)` returns true. Actually this is the [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue%28java.lang.Object%29) of that method. What is the type of your `Map`? `Map<String, String>`?

Comment: Can you edit your question with a sample of code?

Comment: @Patrick Ferreira OP updated with sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check any value contain your string as a substring you have to do the following:

```
for (String value : yourMap.values()) {
    if (value.contains(subString)) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

By the way if your values in the map are really have two different parts, i suggest to store them in a structure with two fields, so they can be easily searched.

Comment: I need them to be that way inside the database. I don't know how could I split them to store in a structure like the one you say. The other solution I see is to add another column to the database with just the group when the value with the name-group is saved

Comment: OK, you do not have to split them, my solution above should work, but will be slower then the structured method. But it does not matters if do not have lots of objects.